# Filling ListView out

Tags: android, listview

I'm working on project and main layout contains ListView. I want to dynamically add subItems to `ListViewItem` View. My main layout is as follows :

main_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

</LinearLayout>
```

And I want to add `TextView` to returned `view` in `getView` with following properties :

1. **Height** : fill_parent
2. **Width** : wrap_content
3. **Text** : Text View Item

   ```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.M_context
           .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

       return convertView;
   }
   ```

**Please note** that, I want to dynamically add subItems to ListViewItem. You can suppose that, I have array of TextView and want to fill my listView using this Items. How can I do this scenario ? I can not find any result with searching on other threads and aslo Google. So, Could any one please help me to solve my problem ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: From where do you want to add the `TextViews`?

Comment: I want to fill my listview using ArrayList<TextView>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my getView() method.

### main.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="#00ff00"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:listSelector="#000000"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:saveEnabled="true" >
</ListView>
```

### item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### Adapter

```
 class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        /*convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.getAppName().setText(str.get(position));*/

        if(position==0)
        {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            convertView = iv;
        }
        else if(position==1)
        {
            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv.setText("text view");
            convertView = tv;
        }
        else
        {
            EditText et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            et.setText("ET go home");
            convertView = et;
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private View pathRow;
        private TextView appNameView = null;

        public ViewHolder(View row) {
            pathRow = row;
        }

        public TextView getAppName() {
            if (null == appNameView) {
                appNameView = (TextView) pathRow.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            }
            return appNameView;
        }
    }
}
```

The commented out portion is the one used to be. The code below it is the one which I used to dynamically generate the view and return them. my listitem.xml still has a textView in it. But the adapter sets the view which we are returning from getView(). This works for me.

I really don;t see the point of the LinearLayout in your item.xml. You can do that in your own code.

Comment: Can you post full of your adapter class and layout that you set on super constructor ?

Comment: I added the code. What I am saying is, the listView has nothing to do with the item.xml.All that matters is what view you are returning from the getView() method. You can prepare the entire view in getView and you can return it. You don't even have to use the convertView parameter. Thats why convertView type is a base class of all views.